# count of Ordered Pairs such that their product is less than a number

Tags: number-theory

I need a mathematical formulation for count of total ordered sets s.t. the product of two elements is less than an number, say n..

count{(i,j)}, s.t.i*j<=n

Answer (score 1):

If $d(x)$ is the number of divisors of $x$, then the answer to your question is given by
$$
D(n)=\sum_{x\le n}d(x).
$$
Determining the behavior of this function is known as [Dirichlet's divisor problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem).  There is not a closed-form solution, but it is known to behave asymptotically as
$$
D(n) \sim n \log n+n(2\gamma-1)+O(\sqrt{n}),
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant; the $O(\sqrt{n})$ error term can be tightened further.

Comment: I don't think we need to do any correcting :)